# Find all directories with exactly two subdirectories

Tags: find, directory

The command

```
find ~ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2
```

doesnt work is there any other solution?

Hm okay i got the solution:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -links 4 -type d
```

Ty for those who tried to solve it

Comment: That command does something totally different to what the subject line says.  What are you actually trying to do?  Please [edit] your question to clarify - I suggest you show a filesystem structure and the results you expect from it.

Comment: @TobySpeight okay im not totally sure if that command works but i will edit it

Comment: The ideal "reproducible example" would be a script we can run in a temporary directory, that creates subdirs and files, then runs your proposed command.  And the expected output of that command, of course.

Comment: @TobySpeight hmm okay im going to do just give me a moment

Comment: If yo have found an adequate answer to your question that is not already posted as an answer, please post it as a proper answer (and accept it) rather than leaving the question unanswered.

Comment: Note that counting the number of hard links would fail on filsystem that allows for creating additional hard links for directories or that implements the dot and dotdot directories in other ways than though hard links.

Comment: If you found a solution, you should post it as a separate answer instead of making it part of the the question.

Comment: Do nested subdirectories "count"? `mkdir -p ~/a/b/c` -- does `a` have two subdirectories?

Comment: @JeffSchaller no they dont count

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        set -- "$pathname"/*/
        [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

The above command will print the pathnames of all directories under the current directory that contains exactly two subdirectories.

The in-line `sh -c` script gets pathnames of found directories from `find` in batches, and will iterate over each batch, one directory at a time.

For each directory, `$pathname`, the shell glob `"$pathname"/*/` is expanded.  This pattern would expand to all the pathnames of all subdirectories directly under `$pathname` (or would remain unexpanded if there were no subdirectories).  The parameter `$#` will contain the number of items that the pattern expanded to, and if this is two, the path to the directory is printed.

The above would not count hidden directories.  For that, use `bash` with its `dotglob` shell option activated:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -O dotglob -c '
    for pathname do
        set -- "$pathname"/*/
        [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
    done' bash {} +
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: i just want to have a directorys with exactly 2 subdirectorys not more than 2 and not less than 2

Comment: @Stefanxyz That's exactly what this does.

Comment: no i get all directorys which have at least 2 subdirectorys so i get directorys which have 2 subdirectorys but also some with 3 or more
okay didnt look: at least the unedited version does it

Comment: @Stefanxyz You would only get directories with more than two subdirectories if you used `-ge 2` or `-gt 2` instead of `-eq 2` in the test.

Comment: @kusalanada tested the secound one shows me also directorys with at least two subdirectorys but i just want to have all with exactly 2 subdirectory

Comment: @Stefanxyz You have an error in your code. The code that I wrote can't return directories that have anything other than exactly two subdirectories.

Comment: my code is correct but i think its becouse im using fedora workstation or vmware has a problem but ty for trying

Comment: @Stefanxyz Update the question with the exact command you are trying and an example of where it gets it wrong.  Running it in a VM should not matter, neither running it on Fedora, OpenBSD or Solaris or any other Unix.

Comment: well im trying to find all directorys with the find command but i got no clue to do it since i worked myself through the manual but i didnt find anything which might work

Comment: and as said i want to see all directorys which have just 2 subdirectorys and thats it

Comment: @Stefanxyz And as I said, it would be nice to see an example where the above code fails in doing that. Note that my code allows there to be _files_ in the directories besides the two subdirectories.  Are you expecting the directories to be empty apart from the two subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

`stat` available? Making use of the No. of hard links being 2 (parent dir link plus `..` link) plus the sub dir count, try

```
stat -c"%n %F %h" * | sed -n '/directory 4/ s///p;'
```

Comment: This only works on filesystems that implement a UNIX filesystem design bug from the 1970s.

Comment: @schily: mind to explain a bit?

Comment: The fact that historic UNIX filesystems implemented '.' and '..' as hardlinks can be seen as a bug and a related behavior is not granted by POSIX. A directory could be shown by `ls` as a zero sized file with link count 1 in the standard case. There are in fact filesystems where your assumption is wrong.